# Hugo's Paginate isn't using my custom filter

Tags: pagination, hugo, paginator

I'm using Paginate to make a list of my projects on my homepage ([index.html](https://github.com/well-made-uk/well-made/blob/master/layouts/index.html)). I'm trying to show only pages with the type "code", but it doesn't work - it shows all kinds of pages (see [here](https://well-made.uk) - note "Calendar" and "About" shouldn't be in this list).

```
{{ $paginator := .Paginate (where .Site.Pages "Type" "code") }}
            {{ range $paginator.Pages }}
            {{ partial "list.html" . }}
            {{ end }}
            {{ partial "paginator.html" . }}
```

The idea of this code is that I create an array of pages of the type "code", and put them into Hugo's Paginate. I then range through the contents of Paginate in the `{{ range }}` block.

This is *sort of* happening, but the filter isn't working at all - it's displaying content outside of the */code/* folder.

[Repo here](https://github.com/well-made-uk/well-made).

I've tried this in many different ways. Applying the filter to the `{{ range $paginator.Pages }}`  sort of works, but also breaks Paginate a bit, since Paginate has a different number of posts than the range it's displaying. I've tried different variations to filter Paginate too, such as `(where Site.RegularPages "Type" "code")`. Nothing has worked!

I've seen posts on StackOverflow (which I can no longer find) saying that this issue is caused by using Paginate more than once on the page, but I've checked through all my files and the theme files, and I can't find it being used anywhere apart from the one instance I'm trying to get to work.

**Edit: I've just changed my code from "Type" to "Section", like this:**

```
{{ $paginator := .Paginate (where .Site.Pages "Section" "code") }}
            {{ range $paginator.Pages }}
            {{ partial "list.html" . }}
            {{ end }}
            {{ partial "paginator.html" . }}
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: Quick note: type isn't defined by the folder it's in, but the type it's assigned in front matter.

Comment: @Rogelio - that's strange! My posts don't have a "type" front-matter, but {{ range where .Pages "Type" "code" }} works correctly anyway.

Comment: First - make sure you are getting the pages you want. 
I.e. that your where statement works - just output direct to the page. 
Confirm you have that working.
Then add paginate.
I got this working locally (not your code, but what you intend) so I assume you have some basic setup problem. So confirm you can dump the pages you want to the webpage - then we can go from there.